# Why do I get this error with tinysort on table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I try to use JQuery's [tinySort](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/TinySort) I get this error

```
Error: this.setArray is not a functionSource
File: http://tinysort.sjeiti.com/scripts/jquery.tinysort.jsLine: 109
```

Here is a JSFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/littlesandra88/wJzNE/

and here is how my table looks like.

Any idea what's wrong?

If it is a difficult problem, does there then exist easier way to sort the columns with a button?

```
<table class="alerts" cellspacing="0">
  <tbody>

    <tr class="header">
      <th class="activity-header"><a href="javascript:sortTable(1)">CWIS</a></th>
      <th class="activity-header">First Name</th>
      <th class="activity-header">Signed</th>
      <th class="activity-header"></th>
    </tr>

    <form action="" method="post">
      <input name="anchor" value="2548" type="hidden">
      <tr>
    <td class="activity-data">2648</td>
    <td class="activity-data">RVV</td>
    <td class="checkbox"> <input name="signed" type="checkbox" checked </td>
    <td class="edit-column"><a href="javascript:showhide('2648');">Details</a> <input value="Save" type="submit"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr id="2548" class="edit-row" style="display: none;">
    <td class="edit-column"> </td>
      </tr>
    </form>

    <form action="" method="post">
      <input name="anchor" value="8249" type="hidden">
      <tr>
    <td class="activity-data">7249</td>
    <td class="activity-data">B</td>
    <td class="checkbox"> <input name="signed" type="checkbox" checked </td>
    <td class="edit-column"><a href="javascript:showhide('8249');">Details</a> <input value="Save" type="submit"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr id="7249" class="edit-row" style="display: none;">
    <td class="edit-column"> </td>
      </tr>
    </form>

  </tbody>

</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its an issue with the script versions.

Either use jQuery 1.4.1 or use the latest version of the tineysort (which got rid of setArray and uses pushStack).

I tried it @ jsfiddle and got rid of the error either way.

Check http://jsfiddle.net/wJzNE/1/

Comment: Ok, now I have inserted the latest tinySort in this http://jsfiddle.net/littlesandra88/wJzNE/2/ . I don't get the error anymore. Do I have to make any changes to make it sort?

Comment: @Sandra: I think the issue is with the selector you are applying the tiny sort on and also there are not td elements with the abbr attribute in your html.. There is no table by the id xtable but you are passing #xtable for the selector.. instead try this one:   `$(".alerts tr:not(.header)").tsort("td:eq("+nr+")",{order:aAsc[nr]});`